# Integrating multiple SPAs in one single SPA using React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

We’re in the process of re-imagining our suite of software applications and need some advice.

Currently, we have 3 fairly large SPAs (coded in react&redux) that we need to rewrite into a single SPA.

What we’d like is to replace each of the individual SPAs with a new SPA written using React&Redux.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr sorry for the mistake, the question is - **how can I achieve that?**

Comment: For the Redux side of things you can use combineReducers on your root apps reducer, giving each one of your three sub-apps there own part of the store.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to rewrite them into a single SPA? What are the issues you are trying to solve?

If you are trying to have the three SPA work together without refreshing the page you could look into using [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview.html). It is a micro front-ends that allows multiple SPA to be knit together to create a single SPA. With this approach, you could optimize load time by hoisting shared dependencies into a single bundle that is loaded once and shared between the three apps.

[Example single-spa project](https://gitlab.com/TheMcMurder/parcels-example)