# User Several SPA in one ASP Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application

There are several team, each of them work on different project or module (for example sale, inventory, security panel and etc ) and each project will be developed as SPA app (React app).

I want put, all of projected in one ASP Core application. In Asp Core there is a Layout (that contain heading, footer, ..) and in `@RenderBody()` 
 section base one user selection, selected module (for example sale, inventory) will be loaded.

I want to know, Is it possible to have such a design?

I check these links:

- [How to configure ASP.net Core server routing for multiple SPAs hosted with SpaServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216929/how-to-configure-asp-net-core-server-routing-for-multiple-spas-hosted-with-spase)
  This question is not same as my question, because i don't want render whole page of SPA in browser, indead I want render one module(one SPA app) in part of Master page.
- [Integrating multiple SPAs in one single SPA using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327296/integrating-multiple-spas-in-one-single-spa-using-react)

But both of them is different from my scenario (because of Layout page)